# What is the number of elements in a set if the ratio of the number of subsets to the number of elements is $\frac {32}{3}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is the number of elements in a set if the ratio of the number of subsets to the number of elements is $\frac {32}{3}$?

At first, I thought that

$$2^n = \frac {32}{3}$$

I see that

$$\text {s} = 2^n$$

Where am i going wrong or where to start?

Comment: you forgot the number of elements in your ratio

Comment: @J.Sadek Thank you so much :)

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{2^n}n = \frac {32}{3}$

n=6

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the fact that for a set with $n$ elements ("number of elements" in the question), there are $2^n $ subsets ("number of subsets" in the question).